# Kendo UI + Angular 2 - Issue including in project

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Just trying to include the simplest of Kendo UI components into my Angular 2 app (using Webpack) and am getting the issue of `Can't bind to 'primary' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.`

I'm importing it in the AppModule as so

`import { ButtonsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';`

and then

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ButtonsModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    ...
```

Even registering with Webpack in a sort of `vendor.ts` file won't change a thing. The files/module itself is loading into the application, so I know the directive is at least declared. I see the plunkr they give on their site works just fine, and I've included all of button's dependencies.

Any ideas? Angular v `2.4.8` and the version of the button directive I'm using is `0.20.1`

Comment: Where do you use kendo button?

Comment: You have to import `ButtonsModule` to the module that consists the component where you are using `button primary="..` in template.

Comment: So I can't import it in the AppModule, and then it's globally available? I've even tried importing it in the SharedModule, and then using it in my HomeComponent (which is on the HomeModule) and no dice there.

Comment: You can import and reexport it in your `SharedModule` so if `HomeModule` imports `SharedModule` then it will also be able to use kendo button

Comment: Hmm...this lead me on the right path. My issue here was that I was lazy loading components, which then they had separate modules that needed Shared to be imported in them. See below -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by importing the ButtonsModule module into a CommonModule, so that it's shared to other modules. The component I was trying to use the Kendo Button in was a lazy-loaded module, and therefore had it's own module that only imported the Shared/common module for the app.

Adding the ButtonsModule import on SharedModule as well as exporting it fixed my issue, as it was then shared everywhere.

Comment: I'd forgotten to export the modules in my SharedModule. Saved an hour or two here, thanks!